# Apache2 not handling high traffic (with Ruby on Rails site)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

Hi I have devloped a website in Ruby on Rails and configured it with apache2 and passenger, normally the site working very smooth but when it get traffic then it slow very down and most time it produces error "Server not responding" (I guess because of apache2 is out of memory) can anyone please suggest how to handle this situation.

When I have gone through the Gtmatix report it was F grade for PageSpeed and YSlow Score.

Please suggest how to scale apache2.

Thanks!

Comment: @WishZone Apache2 with passenger

Comment: yes just saw at your post

Answer (score 0):

**I believe you can check and do following things**

1) Change your app server to PUMA or UNICORN

- https://www.engineyard.com/articles/rails-server

2) Check you server RAM if its less add some new or add SWAP

3) Do some caching and use CDN like Cloudflare to cahce the assets data so that your server will not requested unnecessarily

4) Use New Relic to monitor the server CPU, RAM, DATABASE and can also check the loads

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply can you please suggest how to compress the js, html , css etc in rails because for this time I need some quick solution and I found that if I will compress these items then the loading will be fast.

Comment: You should read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html This is what rails can do for you